# How to sync three laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have three models: Users, Roles, Organizations.
And a pivot table

```
 organization_role_user

  user_id   role_id   organization_id
   1         2          1
```

I can attach a user to an organization with a role like so:

```
$u = User::first();
$r= Role::first();
$u->roles()->first()->attach($r, ['organization_id'=> Organization::first()->id]);
```

and it works fine, the issue now its when I want to update a user: I want to sync pivot table.

I have tried

```
$u->roles()->sync([1=>['role_id'=>$r->id], 2=>['organization_id'=>$o->id]]);
```

But it gives me a `queryexception` saying that `organization_id` does not have a default value. Any idea how should I sync pivot table while I try to update user details, and note I do not want to keep any existing records on pivot for the user I am trying to update.

Comment: Break these out... User -- Role and User -- Organization. Making this 3 headed monster is not a very good way to go if you want to model them as relations... Then it becomes simple ... two relationships...

Comment: I don't want to have a bad db design, I would rather keep it complicated on models then ending up with a bad db design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your user_id is 1

If you call for example:

```
$u->roles()->sync([1, 2]);
```

Laravel will attaching roles_id 1 and 2 to the user_id 1:

```
user_id    role_id
------------------
1          1
1          2
```

If you want to pass additional intermediate table values you should do it like this

```
$u->roles()->sync([1 => ['organization_id' => 2], 2 => ['organization_id' => 2]]);


user_id    role_id    organization_id
-------------------------------------
1          1          2
1          2          2
```

You have to provide a organization_id in your sync function that's why Laravel return `organization_id does not have a default value.`

Comment: wait did you passed organization_id twice why ? and on my solution I tried I was trying to add a organization_id but no work